# Compressing a table with distinct on only two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with no unique ID and two columns that need to be shortened and compressed down to unique values out of every third duplicate. The table looks like this. Every three records in mod_epoch and epoch_15 are the same, as I just need the distinct values. The date and epoch and travel_time_all_vehicles columns can be removed. I need the distinct travel_avg values so I can run 80th and 50th percentiles off of them per TMC.

```
tmc date    epoch   Travel_TIME_ALL_VEHICLES    mod_epoch   EPOCH_15    TRAVEL_avg
113N04415   1012016 184 209 64  21  200
113N04415   1012016 185 210 65  21  200
113N04415   1012016 183 181 63  21  200
113N04415   1012016 188 203 68  22  203
113N04415   1012016 186 209 66  22  203
113N04415   1012016 187 197 67  22  203
113N04415   1012016 191 205 71  23  213
113N04415   1012016 190 209 70  23  213
113N04415   1012016 189 227 69  23  213
```

Comment: please format your code and show expected result

Comment: how do you calculate TRAVEL_AVG? Is it already stored in the DB Or Should be calculated ?

Comment: Can you please provide the desired output in form of a table similar to how you have source table?

Comment: Seems like you are missing a column; Your data has 7 columns and your headings only 6

Comment: It is already stored in the table and I count 7 columns.

Comment: I don't know how to code for this which is why I don't have a example.

Comment: I also don't know how to format things on here.

Comment: Like so: tmc date epoch_15 travel_avg
113n04415 1012016 21 200
113n04415 1012016 22 203
113n04415 1012016 23 213

Comment: You have 6 headings and 7 data columns

Comment: So, you need to do something, but you have no idea how it's done, and somehow we should be able to guess it, without a proper example?

Comment: This works for the most part, but the distinct is melding different travel_avg values into one. select distinct TMC, EPOCH_15, TRAVEL_AVG into I40_2016_WKDAY_10_4_15_FINAL from [dbo].[I40_2016_WKDAY_10_4_15]

Answer (score 0):

So with this post it is hard to say what the author really needs; in general, if you want to have some distinct values from a given table you can you `DISTINCT` t-sql keyword.

```
select distinct EPOCH_15, TRAVEL_avg
from [table]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This mostly solves the problem, expect that there are a few cases where different travel_avg have the same value. So distinct will meld two travel_avg values into one and mess up the calculations.

Comment: @BenZeddicus No it won't; as long as epoch_15 has different values it won't mend travel_avg